# Fastest way to generate a lot of unique small random numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, random

Wondering how to quickly generate lots of unique, small random numbers. When I implemented it like this it slows down exponentially it seems like, to the point where it never finishes, or will take hours to complete. Probably because it creates tons of duplicates toward the end.

```
var intsmap = {}
var intsarray = []
var i = 100000
while (i--) {
  var int = randominteger(6)
  if (intsmap[int]) i++
  else {
    intsmap[int] = true
    intsarray.push(int)
  }
}
// return intsarray

function randominteger(exp) {
  var string = rand(exp)
  return pad(string, exp)
}

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = rand(9) + num
  return s.substr(s.length - size)
}

function rand(exp) {
  var integer = Math.random() * Math.pow(10, exp) << 0
  var string = toString(integer, '0123456789')
  return string
}

function toString(value, code) {
  var digit
  var radix = code.length
  var result = ''

  do {
    digit = value % radix
    result = code[digit] + result
    value = Math.floor(value / radix)
  } while (value)

  return result
}
```

Wondering how to accomplish that but the code works within a few seconds if possible.

**Update**

- I would like for the set of numbers to be distributed evenly over an arbitrary range (in this example 1000000 strings, not necessarily from 0-1000000, eg maybe 5050000 is in there).
- I would like for the numbers to not necessarily be valid numbers, just a string of integers. So for example they can include `01010101` as a valid string, even though that's not a valid number.

Comment: For me the above code takes somewhere between `40-100ms`, what do you expect?

Comment: Your exit condition is `i` reaching `0`. Do you want  `100000` random numbers?

Comment: Sorry, the method implementation totally changed it, wow. Updated the question.

Comment: @LancePollard what method implementation you are talking about?

Comment: `randominteger`, the updated question shows the implementation, which is super slow.

Comment: @LancePollard Still, how many unique random numbers do you want out of `1000000`?

Comment: I want 1000000 exactly

Comment: @LancePollard Then just shuffle the numbers

Comment: @LancePollard Didn't completely understood *update* part. So you just want 1000000 random strings consisting of only digits `0-9`?

Comment: @LancePollard: do you absolutely want an array? I proposed a solution with an object (still iterable if you need). Also, consider that most of your "small" numbers will be greater than 1 million ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an object as a look up and only insert unique random number

```js
var intsmap = {};
var i = 100000;
while (i--) {
  var int = Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 6) << 0;
  if(intsmap[int])
    continue;
  else
    intsmap[int] = true;
}

console.log(Object.keys(intsmap));
```

You can use also use Durstenfeld shuffle after generating number in the given range.

```js
var arr = Array.from({length:1000000}, (_,i) => (i+1));

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}
shuffleArray(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Updated the question with a slow implementation that is causing the problem. See `randomnumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to **shuffle the array of numbers 1 to maxNum**

First create an array

```
var maxNum = 1000000;
var arr = Array(maxNum).fill().map((e,i)=>i+1);
```

Now **shuffle the array**

```
arr.sort(function() {
  return .5 - Math.random();
});
```

Now you have the array of unique random numbers

**Demo**

```js
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

var maxNum = 1000000;
var arr = Array(maxNum).fill().map((e, i) => i + 1);

arr.sort(function() {
  return .5 - Math.random();
});

var endTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log( "Time taken to get " + maxNum + " size random unique number is " + ( endTime - startTime ) + " ms");
```

Comment: you missed the **update** part. OP do not want numbers.

Comment: @Kaiido Have asked OP to clarify a bit on it.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose this approach:

- generate a random number
- cast it to a string (0.1234567812345678)
- and extract 6 substrings of length of 10

Code:

```
var res = {},
    s = "";
for (let i=0; i<1000000; ++i) {
    s = Math.random().toString();
    for (let j=0; j<6; ++j) {
        res[s.substring(2+j, 12+j)] = true; // extract 10 digits
    }
}
```

After 1,000,000 iterations, you have computed 6,000,000 numbers with very little collisions (1,800 in average). So you have your 1,000,000 numbers and more in few seconds.

Comment: Almost same approach as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900884/3702797), but one step further ;-) Good idea to take 6 strings from it, but you are not checking for collision here.

Comment: Why check for collision? I would do 1,000,000+ checks for less than 2,000 collisions.

Comment: They are unique. Take the first 1,000,000 of `res` and check them ;)

Comment: Ok I see, you compute more than needed and grab only the required numbers. I don't know how I feel about this idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
 var acc = 0;
 const result = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
   result.push(acc += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

I think the most expensive operation is the hashtable lookup/insertion, so simply do it without it.

Comment: @kaiido through `acc` ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique big array try to think in other way. Just create range 0 ... 100000 and shuffle it and apply you function that you need for this array.

Answer (score 0):

One place where you might loose performances is in the `Math.random` call.
It's a quite expensive call, and you are calling it a huge number of times to generate your strings.

One solution to leverage it is to grab the whole string from a single result of `Math.random()`.

```js
var intsmap = {}
var intsarray = []
var i = 100000

while (i--) {
  var int = randominteger(6)
  if (intsmap[int]) {
    i++
  } else {
    intsmap[int] = true
    intsarray.push(int)
  }
}

console.log(intsarray);

// It takes the whole string from a single call to 'random'.
// The maximum length is 16.
function randominteger(length){
  return (Math.random() + '').substr(2,length);
}
```